# Getting HttpServletRequestFilterable response in doPost

Tags: java, servlets

I'm using [Mailgun webhooks][1] to send an email and the following servlet to capture the postback.

```
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {

  @Override

  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)

  throws ServletException, java.io.IOException {

    StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();

    PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(stringWriter);

    printWriter.println("MyServlet");

    response.setContentType("text/plain");

    //response.setContentType("application/json");

    response.getOutputStream().print(stringWriter.toString());

  }

  @Override

  public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)

  throws ServletException, java.io.IOException {

    System.out.println("HttpServletRequest below");

    System.out.println(request);

    System.out.println("HttpServletResponse below");

    System.out.println(response);

  }
```

And in my `doPost`, I keep getting the following for my print statements:

```
HttpServletRequest below
org.sitemesh.webapp.contentfilter.HttpServletRequestFilterable@4439aa1f

HttpServletResponse below
org.sitemesh.webapp.contentfilter.ContentBufferingFilter$1@4fa69476
```

What does this mean? I was expecting a JSON response as they have mentioned in their documentation that they are sending JSON response.
[1]: https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/api-webhooks.html

Comment: It means you’re seeing the default toString representation of those instances. You’d probably want to look at the docs for the interfaces used. Or check out a tutorial.

Comment: @DaveNewton I see. Thanks. Also, should I be using `response.setContentType("application/json");` in doGet instead of `response.setContentType("text/plain");` since they are sending JSON ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output you're seeing in your doPost method suggests that you are printing the objects representing the HttpServletRequest and HttpServletResponse rather than the content of the request and response.

In the code you provided, these lines are printing the objects themselves:`

```
System.out.println("HttpServletRequest below");
System.out.println(request);
System.out.println("HttpServletResponse below");
System.out.println(response);
```

To get the content of the request and response (which should contain the JSON data you expect), you should access the methods and properties of the request and response objects.

For example, if you want to access the request's body (the JSON data), you can do something like this:

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
  throws ServletException, java.io.IOException {
    BufferedReader reader = request.getReader();
    StringBuilder jsonRequest = new StringBuilder();
    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        jsonRequest.append(line);
    }

    System.out.println("JSON Request:");
    System.out.println(jsonRequest.toString());
}
```

This code reads the JSON data from the request's input stream and prints it. Maybe this can help :)

Comment: Yeah, that did print the JSON data. Thanks.  So,using `response.setContentType("application/json");` in doGet instead of `response.setContentType("text/plain");` is not needed?

Comment: In your code, you used response.setContentType("text/plain");, which means the response will be treated as plain text. If you want to send JSON as the response, you should use response.setContentType("application/json"); to indicate that the response will be in JSON format. :)

Comment: And if I am using `response.setContentType("application/json"); to indicate that the response will be in JSON format. ` do I still need to do exactly same thing like you did in doPost to get the JSON content out or will there be any change? Thanks again!

Comment: Also, how should I parse this JSON if I want to access specific data from the JSON?

Comment: If you set the response content type to "application/json" in your doGet method, it indicates that the response will be in JSON format. However, the process for generating and sending the JSON response in doGet can be different from doPost. In a usual doGet, you might not receive JSON data in the request but generate JSON content to send as a response.
Maybe this can help: https://www.baeldung.com/servlet-json-response

Comment: This in your doGet might work:  JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject();
    jsonObject.addProperty("key1", "value1");
    response.setContentType("application/json");
    try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
        out.print(jsonObject.toString());
    }

Comment: What package I need to import for ` JsonObject` ?

Comment: From https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson  choose version which is compatible with your project :)

Comment: Thanks.I have jackson library already in my pom.xml so I am wondering if I can use that to access individua json values? All I could see with jackson is that it can convert json string to json object.

Comment: Yes, you can definitely use the jackson library to access individual JSON values too.  :)